# UITableView not loading data with SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to parse a json and load it in the CustomTable, my json parsed successful but could not load the data in the UI, i tried adding test datas, and it displayed. So i guess it has to do with scoping. I have tried using other answers on the same question, but still it did not for work me

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class NewsViewController: UIViewController, 
   UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    var newsPosts = [NewsPost]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        getNewsPost()


    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let post = newsPosts[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell") as? NewsPostCell{
        cell.configureCell(post: post)
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = NewsPostCell()
        cell.configureCell(post: post)
        return cell
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsPosts.count
}


func getNewsPost(){
    Alamofire.request(URL_BASE + NEWS_URL).responseJSON { response in


        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

        if let dict = json.dictionaryObject{
            if let result = dict["data"] as? [NSDictionary]{
                for data in result{
                    guard let title = data["title"] as? String else{
                        return print("title is nil")
                    }
                    guard let href = data["href"] as? String else{
                        return print("href is nil")
                    }
                        guard let image = data["image"] as? String else{
                            return print("image is nil")
                        }
                        guard let content = data["content"] as? String else{
                            return print("content is nil")
                        }
                        guard let _ = data["timestamp"] as? String else{
                            return print("timestamp is nil")
                        }
                        guard let type = data["type"] as? String else{
                            return print("type is nil")
                        }

                        print(type)

                        let post = NewsPost(title: title, href: href, 
                        image: image, timestamp: 
                        "1 day ago", content: content, type: type)

                        self.newsPosts.append(post)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You have no crash ? Have you tried to log what's in newPosts when you're in 'cellForRowAt indexPath' ?

Comment: I have no crash and i logged newPosts and it displayed nothing, its like its not getting there.

Comment: does this line 'print(type)' log the wanted objects ?

Comment: Yes it does, that's the mystery, newsPosts all prints out its value inside the forloop

Comment: you should try to log post right after it's created, and log your postsarray right after you add an entry in it

Comment: I did that, it logged the entry

Comment: and it logged the array with all added entries ?

Comment: Yes it did logged the array after entered data, but logged nil outside the  scope of for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test if your tableview is initialized when before you reload the data :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class NewsViewController: UIViewController, 
   UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    var newsPosts = [NewsPost]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        getNewsPost()


    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let post = newsPosts[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell") as? NewsPostCell{
        cell.configureCell(post: post)
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = NewsPostCell()
        cell.configureCell(post: post)
        return cell
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsPosts.count
}


func getNewsPost(){
    Alamofire.request(URL_BASE + NEWS_URL).responseJSON { response in


        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

        if let dict = json.dictionaryObject{
            if let result = dict["data"] as? [NSDictionary]{
                for data in result{
                    guard let title = data["title"] as? String else{
                        return print("title is nil")
                    }
                    guard let href = data["href"] as? String else{
                        return print("href is nil")
                    }
                        guard let image = data["image"] as? String else{
                            return print("image is nil")
                        }
                        guard let content = data["content"] as? String else{
                            return print("content is nil")
                        }
                        guard let _ = data["timestamp"] as? String else{
                            return print("timestamp is nil")
                        }
                        guard let type = data["type"] as? String else{
                            return print("type is nil")
                        }

                        print(type)

                        let post = NewsPost(title: title, href: href, 
                        image: image, timestamp: 
                        "1 day ago", content: content, type: type)

                        self.newsPosts.append(post)
                    }
                    if self.tableView != nil {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Still the same issues, not displaying the data, seems newsPosts doesn't get pass the scope of the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is when you're calling the gettingNewPost function. The reloadData() function is called right after didLoad, maybe you havent even get the data when you call the function to populate the table. Have you tried to log in the cellForRow function to see if isnt trying to access a nil array?

Comment: Its accessing a nil Array

Comment: So you have to call reload data() after the alamofire request is done

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue, one of the guard is return nil, so it stop the execution of others, so i changed from using guard to the below

```
let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
let href = data["href"] as? String ?? ""
let image = data["image"] as? String ?? ""
let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
let type = data["type"] as? String ?? ""
```